# PostBack causes the JQuery validation in TextBox to not work correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using a TextBox in ASP.NET that can accept only alphabets and space key as input. I am using the following code for this.

```
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        }
        else { return true; }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 32)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

I have added this in two TextBox as below,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_one" CssClass="text" onkeydown="return onlyAlphabets(event);" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="text_two" CssClass="text" onkeydown="return onlyAlphabets(event);" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

The JQuery works in the first text box but in the second text box i am having problems. I can enter alphabets and it also allows special keys from numpad like `/ * - +`. Also it blocks me from using user friendly keys like `backspace, home, arrow keys, etc.` In the first text box the user friendly keys are working and i can only enter alphabets and space (its good). The problem in text box two is because of the post back? If yes how can i avoid that? I tried using the `pageLoad()` but not sure where to add that.

Comment: It seems highly likely that the autopostback is breaking your jQuery... so let me ask why you need AutoPostBack?

Comment: In the second text box i will enter a value and using that value as key, i need to fetch some values from database in C#. This i have to do using `OnTextChanged` so im using PostBack

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the jQuery event to onkeyup or ontextchanged?

Comment: No i havent tried that but even in that case i think post back will break the JQuery..but i will try them now and check

Comment: `onkeyup` also not working..Here i am able to use all keys in textbox

Comment: It's strange because AutoPostBack should only fire when the textbox loses focus... not on key press etc... I suggest you look for an ajax alternative especially because the postback will be invisible to the user and you can then fire the Jquery you want before the ajax post... see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/